# 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

Tags: spring-boot

i have a springboot webapp and when i deployed it on my server on tomcat 7.0.54 then i got following message in catalina.out

```
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

and my application is deploying twice which casue Exception

```
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [inbound] with key 'inbound'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
```

but i tried the same war file on my local system with tomcat 7.0.37 and the application works fine

any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I have 3 detected lol

Comment: @RyanChu how you detected

Comment: I am facing same issue while using maven appengine plugin. Not able to identify what causes the issue.It works OK without appengine plugin. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I resolved this issue by reducing scaling instances to 1. It's not actually issue. It was initializing due to scaling specified in appengine-web.xml

Comment: Facing the same issue when running my app via appengineRun (gradle plugin). Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I removed `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` from my `pom.xml` file and it worked. You may have a library in your `classpath` which has another `WebApplicationInitializer`.

Comment: i tried with tomcat 7.0.75 and then started working thanks for the suggestion i will give a try

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I removed `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs")` from my gradle file and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical situation.  Spring Boot + Tomcat + InstanceAlreadyExistsException on a remote server but worked perfectly on my local Tomcat.

The cause was the remote server having two Host elements in server.xml pointing to the same Tomcat appBase directory (webapps.)  That caused all webapps to be loaded twice.  For some webapps it wasn't a problem, but for mine it was because it tried to register MBeans twice.

My solution was to replace one of the Host elements with an Alias under the other Host element.  Now I just have one Host element and apps are loaded only once each.