# Springboot -> Springboot 2: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

I've got a web app I recently upgraded from springboot to springboot 2. When I deploy it to Tomcat 8 it seems to start but doesn't start fully.

In localhost.2019-09-04.log (Tomcat) I have the following error:

```
2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

I've tried various things from this post:

[2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826879/2-spring-webapplicationinitializers-detected-on-classpath)

but has no luck. How can I find out which package another WebApplicationInitializers might be in?

Comment: Do you happen to have a combination of XML and Java config?

Comment: No, there's no XML config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That log is output from `SpringServletContainerInitializer` which is Servlet 3.0  `ServletContainerInitializer` that handles `WebApplicationInitializer`.

So the most simple way to find out what are these `WebApplicationInitializer` is to create our own  `ServletContainerInitializer` that also handle `WebApplicationInitializer` and print their information to console.

```java
@HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class)
public class FooServletContainerInitializer implements ServletContainerInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(Set<Class<?>> c, ServletContext ctx) throws ServletException {
        for (Class<?> clazz : c) {
            System.out.println(clazz);
            System.out.println(clazz.getResource('/' + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class"));
            System.out.println("----------------");
        }

    }
}
```

<sup>I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983870/339637) for how to print the JAR file path of a class.</sup>

To register it , create a file `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`. Inside this file , include the fully qualified class name of our `ServletContainerInitializer` :

```
org.foo.bar.FooServletContainerInitializer
```

Then it should execute during Tomcat starts.

Comment: seem that it does not load .If the WAR is packaged correctly , after it is deployed to Tomcat , you can find that the file `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` is exploded to the path `$TomcatHomeDir/webapps/your-app-name/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services` ?

Comment: I think we found it another way:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@39cfe31b
Class Name: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer
09-Sep-2019 14:29:30.331 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializer details:
ToString: uk.org.wlma.drs.DrsServletInitializer@6bb5804b
Class Name: uk.org.wlma.drs.DrsServletInitializer

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after doing a new basic spring boot with the bare minimum I still had this problem. The last thing left was to check the innocent application.properties and found with trial and error that there was an invalid property. Once this line was removed, everything worked.

This was the property:

```
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG
```