# Springboot to Springboot 2, How to select WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

I've got a web app I recently upgraded from springboot to springboot 2. When I deploy it to Tomcat 8 it seems to start but doesn't start fully.

In localhost.2019-09-04.log (Tomcat) I have the following error:

```
2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57791571/springboot-springboot-2-2-spring-webapplicationinitializers-detected-on-clas) someone helped me identify that the two web initialises are:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer

```
uk.org.wlma.drs.DrsServletInitializer (mine)
```

But I can't see how to either exclude JerseyAutoConfiguration, as it belongs to the parent springboot dependency or how to get Tomcat8 to select my initializer instead.

This is our pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>wlma.org.uk</groupId>
    <artifactId>wma-drs-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>wma-drs-server-angular</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>   

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>    
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ucanaccess/ucanaccess -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.mygrid.resources.jcoord</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcoord</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Naked Element -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.nakedelement</groupId>
            <artifactId>naked-boot-webapp-angular</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.nakedelement</groupId>
            <artifactId>naked-spring-rest-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wlma.org.uk</groupId>
            <artifactId>wma-drs-msaccess-angular</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.nakedelement</groupId>
            <artifactId>naked-address-finder</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.org.wlma.drs</groupId>
            <artifactId>wma-drs-mapdata-angular</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>uk.co.nakedelement</groupId>
              <artifactId>naked-worldpay</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>

        </dependency>   
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.401</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Solr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>         
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
            <artifactId>greenmail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${appserver.url}</url>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <username>${appserver.user}</username>
                    <password>${appserver.password}</password>
                    <update>true</update>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <operatingSystems>
                        <linux>true</linux>
                    </operatingSystems>
                    <thirtyTwoBitBinaries>false</thirtyTwoBitBinaries>
                    <sixtyFourBitBinaries>true</sixtyFourBitBinaries>
                    <getSpecificExecutableVersions>
                        <googlechrome>2.33</googlechrome>
                    </getSpecificExecutableVersions>
                    <throwExceptionIfSpecifiedVersionIsNotFound>true</throwExceptionIfSpecifiedVersionIsNotFound>
                    <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>${user.home}/selenium-binaries</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                    <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${user.home}</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.13.0</nodeVersion>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run-script build-prod</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.revelc.code.formatter</groupId>
                <artifactId>formatter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configFile>${project.basedir}/naked-element-eclipse-format.xml</configFile>
                </configuration>                
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.lazerycode.selenium
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0.16,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>selenium</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you use Jersey in your project? Show your `pom.xml`, Spring Boot 2 brings in a lot of dependencies by default, and they have autoconfigurations that try to "help" you, but can result in these kinds of surprises.

Comment: pom.xml added to original question.

Comment: Are all those `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies needed? I bet Jersey is pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-web-services`, and if that's not something you actually need, you could just remove the dependency.

Comment: Not related to your question, but PDFBox is at 2.0.16. Consider using the maven versions plugin.