# triple UI loaded on Vaadin

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, payara

I am trying to build a (war) project with Vaadin (23) + Spring boot (2.7+) on Payara (5.2), after a lot of configurations it finally started but the initial UI is loaded 3 times.

As you can see in the picture
[image]

This is the log from the server:

```
 INFO:   13:28:38.744 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] INFO org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension - Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
    
    INFO:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    INFO:   Clustered CDI Event bus initialized
    INFO:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
    INFO:   WebModule[/skeleton-starter-flow-23] ServletContext.log():Initializing AtmosphereFramework
    INFO:   Initializing Soteria 1.1-b01.payara-p5 for context '/skeleton-starter-flow-23'
    INFO:   13:28:39.682 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.DevModeUsageStatistics - Telemetry enabled
    
    INFO:   13:28:39.695 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage - Reading statistics from C:\Users\FiruzzZ\.vaadin\usage-statistics.json
    
    INFO:   13:28:39.718 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.base.devserver.stats.StatisticsStorage - Reading statistics from C:\Users\FiruzzZ\.vaadin\usage-statistics.json
    
    INFO:   13:28:39.735 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] INFO com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeStartupListener - Starting dev-mode updaters in C:\NetBeansProjects\skeleton-starter-flow-23 folder.
    
    INFO:   13:28:39.783 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.scanner.FullDependenciesScanner - 
     List of npm dependencies found in the project:
      - @polymer/iron-icon 3.0.1 com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.IronIcon
      - @polymer/iron-list 3.1.0 com.vaadin.flow.component.ironlist.IronList
    INFO:   13:28:39.789 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.scanner.FullDependenciesScanner - 
 List of @JavaScript found in the project:

INFO:   13:28:39.796 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] INFO com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.scanner.FullDependenciesScanner - Visited 80 classes. Took 26 ms.

INFO:   13:28:39.835 [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] DEBUG com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.VaadinAppShellInitializer - Using com.camioneros.AppShell class for configuring `index.html` response

INFO:   13:28:39.842 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] DEBUG com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskGeneratePackageJson - writing file C:\NetBeansProjects\skeleton-starter-flow-23\target\flow-frontend\package.json.

INFO:   WebModule[/skeleton-starter-flow-23] ServletContext.log():2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
INFO:   onStartup: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@7aa203df
```

Here is an idea about displaying the Spring WebpAppInit detected on classpath, but it just shows one. Took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57792894/1000908)

```
@Theme("my-theme")
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppShell extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppShell.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("onStartup: " + servletContext);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
    
}
```

and finally this is the POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.camioneros</groupId>
    <artifactId>ddjj</artifactId>
    <name>sas-ddjj</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <vaadin.version>23.2.10</vaadin.version>
        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
        
        <!-- this parameter is needed as spring-boot bom overwrites it -->
        <selenium.version>4.5.3</selenium.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </parent>
    
    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Vaadin uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
            <artifactId>hotswap-agent</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-hibernate3-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-deltaspike-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-mybatis-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-myfaces-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-wildfly-el-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-zk-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-weld-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-tomcat-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hotswapagent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hotswap-agent-jbossmodules-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--<defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal>-->
        <plugins>
            <!-- Define newer versions of Java compiler and war plugin to 
            better support latest JDK versions. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

anyone has any idea why is this happening?

This is the only view/router, Autowiring is not working neither (btw), empresaService is always null

```
@Route("")
@PageTitle("SAS - DDJJ")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

@Autowired
private EmpresaService empresaService;

public MainView() {
    System.out.println("Checking autowiring===" + empresaService);
    TextField textField = new TextField("Your name");
    textField.addThemeName("bordered");
    GreetService greetService = new GreetService();
    Button button = new Button("Say hello", e -> {
        Notification.show(greetService.greet(textField.getValue()));
    });
    button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
    button.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
    // Use custom CSS classes to apply styling. This is defined in
    // shared-styles.css.
    addClassName("centered-content");

    add(textField, button, new Button("blable", VaadinIcon.ABACUS.create()));
```

Comment: Do you have a class with a default route? I.e. something that extends component layout and had `@Route("")`?

Comment: Not sure if I scanned your pom.xml correctly, but I think you should use Vaadin 23 with Java 17 (not 11), and you need to have `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` in the dependencies when you are developing a Vaadin application on top of spring-boot.

Comment: Question, are you on purpose running Spring Boot application on Payara? It would probably be better in many ways to go with Jakarta EE project and CDI instead of Spring if you are on Payara.

Comment: @TatuLund yes, I have one, only one Router "" empty

`STaefi` V23 requires at least 11, I am checking about that dependency that you mentioned, I didn't see it in any other example on internet, that's why I didn't include it

`mstahv` yes, I want to make use of some features of Spring and Boot, like IoC, AOP

Comment: @STaefi adding that dependency solved the UI tri-plication, but the autowiring still not working